# Writing object to file

Tags: java, android, serialization, io

I have a method that's supposed to write an object to a file. I've tried a variety of methods but I either don't write to the file or I go into my `catch` statement, my code is as follows:

```
public void createFoo(Foo foo)
{
    ObjectOutputStream out = null;
    try
    {
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\PERSON\\AndroidStudioProjects\\PROJECT\\bar.dat"));
        out.writeObject(event);
        Log.i("CreateFoo", "Write success");
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        Log.i("CreateFoo", "Write - Catch error can't find .dat");
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            out.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.i("CreateFoo", "Write - Failed to close object output stream.");
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried looking at other threads but I'm still having trouble, my Foo object also has `implements Serializable` in its declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Your Android device does not have a `C:\\Users\\PERSON\\AndroidStudioProjects\\PROJECT\\` directory, largely because Android is not Windows, so Android does not have drive letters. Also, you cannot write to just any directory in Android -- your app is limited to [internal storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), [external storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), and (on Android 4.4+) [removable storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html).

Also, in the future, when you ask questions on Stack Overflow about how your app is crashing, [use LogCat and post the stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this).

Comment: I'm using the Android Studio emulator so I thought it would look in its file directory for the .dat. Will storing to external storage store in a Windows directory?

Comment: @Dan External storage for the emulator is a disk image. Files your app on the emulator writes to external storage will be inside that disk image file.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing

```
out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\PERSON\\AndroidStudioProjects\\PROJECT\\bar.dat"));
```

with

```
File outFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "bar.data");
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outFile));
```

Did the trick, thanks for the help!